# SSRS Report Builder conditional formatting- compare the left most characters of 2 fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Somewhat elementary questions:

Task at hand: Aiming to understand if there is a way to compare the left most values between 2 fields, and if there is a difference, trigger a formatting change.

I've been successful comparing fields as they are, but this is a bit different.

[image]

Example: comparing 2 fields, [LEVEL_DETAIL_01]  and [LEVEL_DETAIL_01_AU]  (these are the Var Level 1 fields being compared from 2 different tables in my attached example), and, if there is a difference in the numeric characters, then, I will trigger formatting the text.

In my example, compare '**201** LABR' with '**201** LAB' - and if these values match, do nothing.

Currently:

```
=IIF(Fields!PAR_ACT_STRCT_01.Value=Fields!ACCT_UNIT_LEVEL1_NAME.Value,
"Transparent","Yellow")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You said fields are in different tables, do you mean different tables (Tablix) in the report or different datasets or both? You title also says "left most characters" but you don't specify how many characters or if the number is dynamic. I'm sure what you want is achievable but we'll need more info. My initial guess if you'll use LEFT() and LOOKUP() combined, but I'll post a proper answer once you've added more detail (if I can)

Comment: Ah, i see. - apologies for lack of info - "first time poster, long time lurker"

The full query joins the tables I need, and I'm using a single dataset - the number portion for each level type is stagnant -VarLevel 1 has 3 numerics before the alpha, Level 2 has 1.  My initial thought was to use some sort of 'Left()' but was missing the target.

Comment: No problem, answer coming in a few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bit of overkill but see how you go.

```
=
IIF(
    VAL(LEFT(Fields!PAR_ACT_STRCT_01.Value, Instr(Fields!PAR_ACT_STRCT_01.Value, " ")-1)) =
    VAL(LEFT(Fields!ACCT_UNIT_LEVEL1_NAME.Value, Instr(Fields!ACCT_UNIT_LEVEL1_NAME.Value, " ")-1)),
    Nothing, 
    "Yellow"
    )
```

This assumes that the value you want to check always has a space immediately after it. It also assume that it can ignore any non-numeric characters before the first space (so `201A test` would *equal* `201B something` as only the numeric data before the first non-numeric data is considered)

If we take each line, the first one simplified reads `VAL(LEFT(myColumn, Instr(myColumn, " ")-1))` . Staring in the middle, `InStr()` finds the first space, we then use `LEFT()` to get the leftmost characters up to `first space - 1`. Finally we use `VAL()` to get only the numeric part of the string. The VAL counld be removed if you always have numbers then a space - like I said, a bit of over kill.

The we repeat the logic for the 2nd column and compare the values.

If they match then set the background to `Nothing`. This is equivalent to "Transparent" and is the default value that SSRS uses. If not return "Yellow".

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to assist!